# At work my PC is on a VLAN. When I use VPN, will I be in the VLAN again?

Tags: networking, vlan

I do not understand how that works. I know VPN allows me to be on the network (as if I was there). But how is it connected with port mapping on switches that creates VLANs?
In other words, how does it work that even when remotely, I will still in the correct VLAN my PC at work is?

My point is, the VLANs are for securiy reasons (for me not to be able to see other departments/VLANs data)..how this is handled with VPN?

Comment: This is very interesting questions. In theory most networks are setup to have a default vlan (tagged with number 0 lets say) then vlan 10, vlan 20, vlan 30 for example. Your VPN will most likely default to vlan 0 just because its the default. What device supplies the VPN a Server, Firewall, dedicated VPN hardware? Again vlan traffic is tagged so you will most likely have to tell the VPN to be part of the vlan; issue is will you put everyone in that vlan who connects to the VPN.

Comment: If the VPN is configured to connect you to the VLAN then, yes, you would be connected to the VLAN.

Comment: The thing is, how it knows which one is your VLAN if you are not using devices in the office, the ports of which are already set for VLANs.

Comment: @Thomas - Your comment does not make sense.

Comment: It does. Do you know how VLANs work, right? You are physically in the office and the device you use is - by setting of ports on the switch - assigned to a VLAN. But if you connect REMOTELY, how the VPN server should know who are you in terms of what VLAN you belong in?

Answer (score 3):

First off VLANs do not have anything to do with port mapping and are not specifically for security.  They are virtual logical units.  A VLAN is a virtual LAN. In technical terms, a VLAN is a broadcast domain created by switches. Normally, it is a router creating that broadcast domain. With VLAN’s, a switch can create the broadcast domain.

When you VPN in, whatever is managing VPN connections, places you in the right VLAN.  This gives you access to the network you need.

Comment: I beg to differ - static VLANs are basically done assignements of ports..

Comment: +it does not explain how VPN knows which VLAN you (connected externally) belong in.

Comment: @Thomas - Please provide evidence to support your comment.

Comment: For example: http://sysnetnotes.blogspot.in/2013/07/what-is-difference-between-static-vlan.html   Static vlans- port based.

Comment: @Thomas It does explain: "When you VPN in, whatever is managing VPN connections, places you in the right VLAN."   So, for example, you VPN into the network via a VPN server device, and that device  is in (say) VLAN99.   Unless the VPN server/system itself specifically has the ability to handle which VLAN you end up in, you'll end up in VLAN99 since you're routing through the VPN device that's in VLAN99.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to worry, starting a VPN client will not alter your local connection in anyway.

VPNs are often misunderstood, but they are quite simple. Apart from the encryption of the communication, what they do is to alter your routing table, *i.e.* the locally available instructions for routing correctly your communication packets toward their final destination.

Normally, you have a local router, in your LAN. Also, you have a local connection (to your LAN) which does not require a router at all. Your routing table basically says: if you want to contact someone local, try it directly without passing through the router. For anything else, go through the router.

The VPN is interested only in that *for anything else*, because it substitutes to your local router the (remote) VPN server you have contacted. All packets coming out of your pc now appeared destined to the remote VPN server, so that your local router lets them through. Once they reach the remote VPN server, the packets are decrypted, their final destination is brought to light, and they are routed for their intended final destination.

You see from this layman's description that a VPN is simply not interested in your local communications, which are  neither encrypted nor routed through the remote server. In other words, your local traffic is totally **unaffected**: if you were in a VLAN you remain in a VLAN, if you were in just a LAN you remain in a LAN.